# Enciphering and Deciphering by Shuffling in Python

Tags: python, random, indexing, random-seed

I am writing a program that enciphers (and will eventually decipher) a given string.

The encipher function takes two arguments: the string and a seed value.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def random_encipher(string,seed):
   random.seed(seed)
   alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

   #shuffle alphabet
   random.shuffle(alphabet)

   #assign index to each letter in alphabet
   for letter in alphabet:
       letter = ord(letter)-97
```

To sum all that up, basically I'm shuffling the alphabet and assigning each letter a number value ("a" = 0, "b" = 1, . . .)

Here's what I need help with:

I need **string[0]** to be printed as **alphabet[0]** (which is the shuffled alphabet, therefore with the current seed value, alphabet[0] = "e").

But for each letter of the string, not just the zero index.

Comment: Fix your code indentation

Comment: @thefourtheye that was just from copying and pasting my code into the text box. it's properly indented in the real thing

Comment: Before everything, you have a problem in your for loop. As you are manipulating immutable types (strings) using the iteration variable `letter`, any assignment to this variable inside the for loop will be overridden at the next iteration. Otherwise said, your for loop is doing nothing.

Comment: What is the point of the assigning the seed to the seed variable?

Comment: @jakekimds i suppose nothing, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that?

```
>>> import random
>>> def random_encipher(string,seed):
   random.seed(seed)
   alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

   #shuffle alphabet
   random.shuffle(alphabet)

   ciphers = []
   #assign index to each letter in alphabet
   for letter in string:
       index = ord(letter)-97
       cipher = alphabet[index]
       ciphers.append(cipher)
   return "".join(ciphers)

>>> random_encipher("foobar", 3)
'fwwqgc'
```

The point in using a list, is that as strings are immutable, appending to a string requires the string to be copied which is costly. Appending to a list and merging the elements at the end is a better choice (or use a [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/io.html?highlight=stringio#io.StringIO)).

Answer (score 1):

What you are effectively doing is creating a mapping between letters.

Luckily, python actually has an easy-to-use map object (`dict`):

So, to create a random mapping:

```
keys = string.ascii_lowercase
# this shuffles the string
values = ''.join(
    random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, len(string.ascii_lowercase))
)
mapping = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

And we want the reverse of this mapping for deciphering, so we use `dict comprehension`:

```
reverse_mapping = {v: k for k, v in mapping.iteritems()}
```

Now it's simply a matter of using the mapping on ciphering and deciphering:

```
def translate(s, mapping, missing=' '):
    return ''.join([mapping.get(c, missing) for c in s])
```

And to use the translation function:

```
encrypted = translate("my string", mapping)
print encrypted
# verify deciphering works
decrypted = translate(encrypted, reverse_mapping)
print decrypted
```

The whole thing together:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import string
import random
# ... set 'seed', or factor to a function
random.seed(seed)
keys = string.ascii_lowercase
values = ''.join(
    random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, len(string.ascii_lowercase))
)

mapping = dict(zip(keys, values))
reverse_mapping = {v: k for k, v in mapping.iteritems()}

def translate(s, mapping, missing=' '):
    return ''.join([mapping.get(c, missing) for c in s])

encrypted = translate("my string", mapping)
print encrypted
# verify deciphering works
decrypted = translate(encrypted, reverse_mapping)
print decrypted
```

Output:

```
up jsqlao
my string
```

Comment: The point of the seed is that with the same seed you get the same shuffle, thus the same mapping. This serves as the key.

Comment: @Cilyan thanks, I didn't know that's how `random` works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up using:

```
def random_encipher(s,n):

     random.seed(n)

     alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

     #shuffle alphabet
     random.shuffle(alphabet)
     print alphabet

     #build empty list
     list = []
     string = ""

     #build enciphered string
     for letter in s: 
         if letter.isalpha(): #if character is a letter, print as corresponding index in shuffled alphabet
             list.append(alphabet[ord(letter)-97],)
             word = string.join(list)
         else: #includes punctuation, spaces, etc.
             list.append(letter),
             word = string.join(list)

     print word

random_encipher(s,n)
```